# Protractor is waiting even after given wait time is finished

Tags: typescript, async-await, protractor

I am working on automation with protractor and typescript, and I have a loader on page which appears in 1-2 seconds and disappears in nearly 5 seconds. I am using protractor explicit wait , but instead of waiting of given time (say - 3 seconds) its waiting for longer than that but with time interval of 3 seconds.And the code gets stuck in timeout error.[image]

Below is my code.

```
    public async waitForLoader{ 
        const until = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
      await browser.wait(until.visibilityOf(this.eleSmallLoader), 3000);
      await browser.wait(until.invisibilityOf(this.eleSmallLoader), 3000);
      }
```

I have also attached the screenshot for terminal which is showing the time out with 3 second interval.

Comment: please the part of the code where you call that function

Answer (score 1):

Just keep the timeout longer for both lines (line 80, 81), say 10000 ms. You do not have to worry about these numbers, as the wait will be over as soon as the condition is satisfied.